# Get database Data in Object

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, java-stream

I have table Car in database and I want to fetch all information of it in the object and then I want to use the java stream to filter the data and show that data.

I tried to get the data in List<Car> car but it did now work

Comment: Please read the guidelines on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). At the very least, we need to see what you’ve tried.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<Car> findCarLessThan20kAndYellowColor() {

    return carRepository.findAll()
            .stream()
            .filter(price -> price.getPrice() < 20_000.00)
            .filter(color -> color.getColor().equalsIgnoreCase("yellow"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I wanted to do filter using java stream
Finally found the solution you can directly use stream after findAll() method.